# Why do my $PATH environment always reset after I open a new terminal on my mac?

Tags: macos, path, zsh, environment

Usually I will `nano .zsh_profile`
Then I will edit the path

```
#PYTHON
export PATH=/Users/ffff/Library/Python/3.8/bin:$PATH

# JAVA
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

#ANDROID
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/ffff/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$PATH
```

then I will save and exit
Then I will

```
source .zsh_profile
```

I will test the Java and ADB all is good, but one I open a new Terminal from my mac, it will say ADB and JAVA and Android_HOME not found

Why is it not persist? Did I miss out anything? My mac version is 12.2.1

Comment: There are several files executed on starting a new zsh instance. Which files are actually used, depends on the kind of the zsh. This is described in the zsh man page. The file `.zsh_profile` is **not** one of them, i.e. it will never be automatically processed, unless you source it explicitly.

Comment: In particular, have a look at `/etc/zshenv`. If this file exists, it will be sourced by **every** new zsh instance.

Comment: `/etc/zshenv` should be kept as small as possible precisely *because* it is sourced by every new instance, including non-interactive shells to run scripts, and *cannot* be disabled. It (and `.zshenv`) are intended for `zsh` shell settings that can't be inherited from a parent shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.zsh_profile` file, has no special meaning. This is probably a confusion form `Bash`, where the `bash_profile` is executes for login shells. In `Zsh`, that equivalent would be `~/.zprofile`. You might have some code in your `.zshrc`  file, that overrides the `PATH` variable  with something else. Because, as oppsed to `.zprofile`, the `.zshrc` file gets executed for *every* interactive non-login shells.

So my advice, checkout `.zshrc` and see if there's something overriding the `PATH` there, if so, maybe you want to change that, and ***NOT*** to execute these commands you want to add for *every* time a shell is opened, you should put them in `.zprofile`, so they only get executed once at login.

Comment: @Dan: Not quite true. `.zsh_profile` has no special meaning. login shells would source `.zprofile`.

Comment: Continue using `.zprofile` instead of `.zshrc`; `.zshrc` is sourced for *all* interactive shells, which means you could (in theory) make your path longer and longer if you start explicit interactive shells from inside a session which already has the modified `PATH`.

Comment: @user1934428 Thanks! I've edited my answer

Comment: @chepner that's true I also edited my answers to take your info into account.

Comment: @chepner : Basically you are right, but if you put into the .zshrc a `typeset -aU path`, the PATH won't get longer for subshells. Having the PATH settings in .zshrc has the advantage that you can (on the fly) add directories to the path and just open a subshell (with `zsh` or from your IDE) to see the effect.